# Integration between Todoist and asana/github

Tags: productivity

My team prefers to document non code issues into asana and code issues into github.

I personally control my life using Todoist.

Currently I need to check and write issues multiple times

E.g. The same issue I need to write in github and Todoist

Or in asana and Todoist

When I mark something as done or edit its contents I need to do twice too.

When I create issue in github for eg using zapier or ifttt, the same issue shows up in Todoist but is in inbox and I still need to arrange it in the right folder or labels. And zapier or ifttt definitely cannot solve the mark as done issue

I have already paid for premium Todoist. I don't mind paying for this feature.

The reason I want to set it up like this is because my brain now works like this:

- Module: record / mark / edit non code issues that team and myself should know
- User interface: asana
- Module: record / mark / edit code issues that team and myself should know
- User interface: github
- Module: what I should be working on now
- User interface: Todoist

How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: Did you research Web Scraping? http://www.garethjames.net/a-guide-to-web-scrapping-tools/ using web scraping tools you could somehow make this work for you?

Comment: I prefer to use something that exists rather than writ le code

Comment: Have you already checked out IFTTT?

Comment: My question has this line that says "and zapier or ifttt definitely cannot solve the mark as done issue"

Answer (score 2):

All three services have APIs: [Todoist's](https://developer.todoist.com/#api-overview), [Github's](https://developer.github.com/) and [Asana's](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/overview).

I'd recommend APIs rather than webscraping since APIs are intended to be stable, so won't break if they change their webpage layout or whatever.

As for interfacting with their APIs, they're RESTful so anything which can request a webpage should work. I'd personally use Python's [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) module, you might find [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301938/making-a-request-to-a-restful-api-using-python) useful.

Comment: API's could be harder to set up, and less legal stuff (recent rulings) i agree with Gyppo.

Comment: Is there something better than write my own code to consume api? Some service that exists already?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, let me know if you find anything.

Comment: an interesting article on web scraping: https://blog.hartleybrody.com/web-scraping/